# How to get my GNUPG Elgamal private key exponent?

Tags: cryptography, gnupg

I have tried googling around. The closest solution I get is:

private.key contains the private key file.

```
$pgpdump -i private.key
```

But this only gives me the following:

```
ElGamal p
ElGamal g
ElGamal y
Encrypted Elgamal x
some other information of crypto
```

It shows the value for p,g,y, but not x. How can I find out the value of x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates your private key is encrypted with a passphrase. `pgpdump` does not decrypt private keys to display them.

With GnuPG 1 and 2, you can at least export unencrypted subkeys using `gpg --export-options export-reset-subkey-passwd --export-secret-subkeys [key-id]`. This will also print the secret `x` part of your key. For GnuPG 2.1, this option was removed.

I'm not aware of a similar option for primary keys without changing GnuPG's source code.